# Using multiprocessing [joblib used] in python, what does it mean if Wall Time >> CPU Time? (240 seconds vs. 0.22 seconds)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib, cpu-time, wall-time

I'm running a function in parallel with python multiprocessing module. This function takes images as input, and outputs some measurements. The problem is that, I compared the results of time.time() vs time.clock(), it seems the wall-time is WAY longer than the cpu-time. Something like 240 seconds vs. 0.22 seconds!!

If I understand correctly, this means CPU spends less than 1 second on executing my function, and for most of the time, I'm waiting for reading/writing/disk etc. Does this sound normal? I'm using a public super-computing center (it's very powerful though）, so I'm not sure whether it was because other users are also using the cpu nodes and I had to wait?

The following is my code, could you point out if any part of the code might be the cause? Thank you very much!

```
import cv2
import glob
from joblib import Parallel,delayed   # this is for parallel computing
import time as t
from Function_ImageMeasure_sz import salinency, color_HSV,rot_balance

mypath='C:/Research/Data/Images/*.jpg'
# define function that will be executed in parallel
def get_measurement(file_name):
    img = cv2.imread(file_name)  # read image
# the following steps are computing some metrics over the input image
    contours,ind,centroid=salinency(img)
    d_rot,balance=rot_balance(img,centroid)
    color_rank, color_tone,bright_stat,saturate_stat,clear_dull,symmetry=color_HSV(img)
    result=[d_rot,balance,centroid,color_rank,color_tone,bright_stat,saturate_stat,clear_dull,symmetry]
    return result

# call function 
files=glob.glob(mypath) # input all images in the same folder
njob=2 # define how many threads/pipelines in parallel

t1=t.clock()
t3=t.time()
# this is implement the function in parallel
results=Parallel(n_jobs=njob,backend='multiprocessing')(map(delayed(get_measurement),files)) 
t2=t.clock()
t4=t.time()

# output results
print 'processing %s image takes %s seconds (wall-time), %s seconds (cpu-time) with %s threads/cores'%(len(files),t4-t3,t2-t1,njob)`
```

Comment: Update details: when use njob=2 (2 threads in parallel), wall-time VS. cpu-time is like : 240s VS 0.22 s; when I use njob=28, wall-time VS. cpu-time goes to: 33s VS 0.17s. I tested njob=28 mainly because with the public super-computing resource I'm using, the computation CPU-node allocated to me has 2 CPUs, with 14 cores per CPU.

Comment: Clearly the process is heavily I/O bound.